# How to convert forms to xpages programatically?

Tags: xpages

I need to convert Notes Form to Xpage programatically ?

If anyone knows , please help me . 
Thanks in advance..

Comment: if my answer helped you can you mark it as top answer so other developers will know what to do when facing the same issue. if not can you add more details and I or others may be able to offer help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a transformer from GBS that does this:

http://www.gbs.com/en/GBS-Xcelerator-Suite

Or an article (not programmatic) on how to do it:

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPages_with_large_notes_forms

However i'd look at articles like the following which are arguing whether doing something like this is missing the point of XPages or not and whether it would be a benefit to re write and gain the full advantages of XPages instead of a hybrid.

http://www.geniisoft.com/showcase.nsf/archive/20090101-0857

Comment: +1 XPages should NOT copy forms to leverage their full potential

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try and let you know whether it will be done or not.

Comment: The primary advantage of programmatic conversion applies when you want to modernize thousands of apps rapidly without losing the existing business logic. On a per-form basis, it's always better to design the XPage manually.