# Creating Dynamic Xpages

Tags: xpages

I have seen some tools which are generating xpages automatically, from the existing lotus design(forms & Views)...using DXL exporter & XML conversion or whatsoever.

As i'm new to Xpage ,I'm curious to know  how to Create a Xpage Dynamically?

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2):

An XPage is simply XML in a file with the extension .xsp, There is no trick here simply output the correct XML to a file. These tools would convert existing controls to XPages controls or where they can already be used, simply wrap them up in a container I would imagine.

The best approach however is to manually code these as you will loose a lot of the benefits of XPages by relying on these tools to create it for you. These tools are generally for large scale applications that would take far too long to rewrite or they are depending on legacy code etc.

A similar question was asked on how to do this and I answered it here:

[How to convert forms to xpages programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278614/how-to-convert-forms-to-xpages-programatically/10278851)

Comment: I do agree Manual code is pretty pretty good, bt the sametime generating dynamic Xpages will help us to create application with more and more field with Less funtionalities.

Comment: If you have an existing notes application and you need it done quickly then yes use the tool or follow the example I have in my other post. But if your end goal is to upgrade your applications to XPages to take advantage of all it has to offer then there is no choice you will need to recreate it, you can still use views, forms and agents but the UI and some logic will need to be updated. Without doing this there are many features that you will not be able to avail of such as the new mobile and social controls from the ExtLib, which is what most people are moving to use

Comment: there is no magic solution that will offer the best of both, you will need to decide what your business case is for upgrading and then go with that option

Answer (score 2):

There is no way (at least not without a lot of hacking) to create XPages on the fly. The XML is just the "source" of the java source that designer creates, then compiles when you build your application.

Since XPages are ultimately an implementation of JSF, you can write Java classes that can manipulate the component tree at runtime to inject controls, etc. But this is not a trivial task.

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to XPages I would strongly recommend you get up to speed on building XPages before trying to build something that will dynamically take forms / views and convert to XPages on the fly. Those who have done that kind of thing had already built up considerable knowledge of building XPages applications and the Java classes that actually do all the code, as well as understanding what client functionality can and can't be done in XPages and how to work around it. Take an @Prompt or @DialogBox or the LotusScript equivalents, for example. That needs to run SSJS, then wait for response from the user before continuing with code. That is probably beyond many experienced XPages developers, let alone one new to XPages. If you have considerable Java experience, you might have a heads tart, but otherwise I would highly advise learning to walk before you try to run.

Comment: I completely disagree with this answer. I am in the exact same spot as OP and I think, despite not working with XPages for long, I would appreciate an answer on how to compile the dynamically built source code of an XPage.

Comment: The build process converts the XML "source" of an XPage into .java classes which get compiled down into .class files, which is what the server / Notes Client run. If you edit those .java files, any build of the application will overwrite your changes. You can't inject code into those files as far as I know. As Jeremy says, you need to manipulate the component tree at runtime. In addition to what Jeremy says, you may possibly need to re-inject them as appropriate after a partial refresh, probably retrieve compositeData in Java. An OSGi plugin may be a better repository for the code than an NSF.